# How can I retrive all patients information with their temperatures by mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables on my database, one for the patients, one for their temperatures, and one table that contains the patient's id and the temperature's id as a primary key.

patient table;

```
+----+------+--------+------------+
| id | name | gender | birth      |
+----+------+--------+------------+
|  1 | Hind | F      | 2015-01-01 |
|  2 | Saad | M      | 2016-01-01 |
+----+------+--------+------------+
```

patient_info table:

```
+------+------+
| id_t | id_p |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    2 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

temperature table :

```
+----+-------------+
| id | temperature |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |        37.9 |
|  2 |          37 |
|  3 |          38 |
|  4 |        38.4 |
+----+-------------+
```

So what I want is to retrieve all patients with their temperatures and here is what I have done :

```
mysql> SELECT p.*, t.* FROM patient p INNER JOIN patient_info pi ON pi.id_p = p.id INNER JOIN temperature t ON t.id = pi.id_t;
+----+------+--------+------------+----+-------------+
| id | name | gender | birth      | id | temperature |
+----+------+--------+------------+----+-------------+
|  1 | Hind | F      | 2015-01-01 |  1 |        37.9 |
|  2 | Saad | M      | 2016-01-01 |  1 |        37.9 |
+----+------+--------+------------+----+-------------+
```

but that is not what I want, I need to know all Hind's and Saad's temperatures 
Thanks all

Comment: I think your ID's are backwards on your Patient_Info table, or you example data here is bad. You show us here two patients of ID `1` and `2`, but you have 4 patients in your Patients_Info table (field `id_p`). You can't show temp information on patients 3 and 4 because they don't exist in your patient table.

Comment: Yes. There are only two patients here, with one temperature reading each (both having the same reading, as it happens) - although why temperature has its own table is beyond me!!!

Comment: @JNevill You are right, my mistake, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I expect you're really after something like this - although it doesn't really make sense to store temperatures in a separate table...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS patient;

CREATE TABLE patient
(patient_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,dob DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO patient VALUES
(101 ,'Hind','F','2015-01-01'),
(102 ,'Saad','M','2016-01-01');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS patient_temperature;

CREATE TABLE patient_temperature
(patient_id INT NOT NULL
,temperature_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(patient_id,temperature_id)
);

INSERT INTO patient_temperature VALUES
(101,1),
(101,2),
(102,3),
(102,4);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temperature;

CREATE TABLE temperature
(temperature_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,temperature DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO temperature VALUES
(1,37.9),
(2,37),
(3,38),
(4,38.4);

SELECT p.*
     , t.*
  FROM patient p 
  JOIN patient_temperature pt 
    ON pt.patient_id = p.patient_id 
  JOIN temperature t 
    ON t.temperature_id = pt.temperature_id;
+------------+------+--------+------------+----------------+-------------+
| patient_id | name | gender | dob        | temperature_id | temperature |
+------------+------+--------+------------+----------------+-------------+
|        101 | Hind | F      | 2015-01-01 |              1 |       37.90 |
|        101 | Hind | F      | 2015-01-01 |              2 |       37.00 |
|        102 | Saad | M      | 2016-01-01 |              3 |       38.00 |
|        102 | Saad | M      | 2016-01-01 |              4 |       38.40 |
+------------+------+--------+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: "it doesn't really make sense to store temperatures in a separate table" - actually it is common in medical systems to have data dictionaries of valid values e.g. picking lists is a common UX paradigm. When you think about it, the cardinality of the set of valid temperatures for a person is small. From a practical point of view, most SQL products/coders don't do so well when it comes to constraints but foreign keys are the exception... that said, you've omitted FKs for your schema :)

Comment: ...What maybe doesn't make sense is to record a temperature without reference to a date/, time or event.